# If I want to model a bivariate distribution that is symmetric about (0,0) using copula, what copulas can I use?

Tags: density-function, copula, symmetry

If I want to model bivariate data $\{X_i,Y_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ using copula. The true joint density of $(X,Y)$ denoted as $f_{XY}(,)$ is unknown, but I know it's symmetric about (0,0) in the sense that
$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_{XY}(-x,-y)$.

What copula functions can I use that can preserve this symmetric feature?

Comment: I thought copulas are purposed for asymmetric elliptical joint distributions. or is this just common practice and not the rule